# network bridge query with hamachi?

Tags: networking, bridge, tcpip, hamachi

I have an embedded hardware in one city connected with my mac laptop via ethernet.
I wish to connect that hardware to the server in a different city. The server is not on the internet but I have a colleague who's win10 laptop is online and connected to the server's network via ethernet.
How is it possible to get the hardware connect the the remote server using it's valid IP?
Can hamachi help in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want anybody else to access your embedded hardware, so I recommend setting up a VPN between your colleague's laptop and the remote server.

For example with [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net); no third party service required, and it's open source.

The remote server needs to have a public IP address.

Of course you can also use other VPN services like Hamachi, but it's not really necessary if your remote server does have a public IP.